# Get location of all current touches on Windows Phone screen

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

How do I get the location of all current touches on the phone's screen in a mobile Silverlight application? The technique described at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff434208.aspx seems to only apply to XNA applications. Otherwise, it gives the error "The name 'touchPanel' does not exist in the current context".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [article](http://www.eugenedotnet.com/2011/01/w16-handling-multi-touch-events-in-windows-phone-7-applications/) should help you determine all the touchpoints in a Silverlight WP7 Application.

The idea behind is to use **TouchPointCollection** in Codebehind.